Are there any neat ways to get warnings or errors if a numpy or scikit-learn operation is slow because of non-contiguous arrays?
This is something that seems to bite me repeatedly when using numpy for anything (most often things like scikit-learn).
It's very easy to make an array non-contiguous (all it takes is a.T), then pass it to some scikit-learn operation. The operation may end up taking 5 minutes instead of 30 seconds, and, if you are lucky, you feel it's slower than it should be.
For this reason, I would absolutely love to have an ability to detect matrix operations performed slowly on non-contiguous arrays. Probably a silenceable warning would be the ideal.
Are there any reasonable approaches to this? One desperate idea that comes to my mind would be to hook BLAS functions and warn there, but I'm not even sure numpy does everything relevant using BLAS.

I think you should open an issue on Scipy's github because AFAIK this is not implemented and it would require a global check called on all functions (AFAIK not done). The thing is the speed of the non-contiguous access is dependent of the target architecture and the actual code so it may sometimes not be significantly slower (though often). BLAS functions are not the only ones that are called by Scikit and Numpy. In fact, BLAS functions are pretty rare inside Numpy except for np.dot, np.einsum and few other ones. Lapack functions (eg. for solvers) may call BLAS ones too.
